# Is source_file.c necessary to present in the directory, where we trying to do gdb for the executable of source_file.c?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, gnu

I am trying gdb for the final executable of  **source_file.c**, the 'list' command.

It is not working as I expected, since I only have an executable and not `source_file.c` in that directory. Is that the expected behavior?

Scenario as below:

```
(gdb) b main
(gdb) list
1   source_file.c: No such file or directory.
in source_file.c
```

So, is it necessary to have `source_file.c` in that pwd, for trying to start gdb for the executable of `source_file.c`?

Answer (score 3):

A binary that was compiled for debug has additional information added to help the debugger. This this includes the file name and line number of each instruction and symbol. But it does not include the source code.

If you want source level debugging you have to have the source file but it doesn't have to be in the same directory. You can specify the directory that contains your source file with the "directory some_dir_name" command.

Without the source file a debugger is still a useful tool. You can still do almost everything. You can set breakpoints, disassemble code, examine memory, etc. But it will not show you the code or variable names as you do so. One command that does not work is "list." The assembly equivalent is "disassemble."

There are several valid reasons one might debug without a source file. I've spent time working on an OS that ostensibly only had an assembly debugger. But I had access to the source to guide my way. But in today's world its generally easier to avoid.

GDB also support remote debugging. This would allow you to run gdb on the machine that has the code.

As previously mentioned the documenentation has a good description: https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

Comment: you mean to say it is MUST to have source_file.c either in present directory or some other directory ,my question is can i do gdb with only gdb enabled image without source_file.c?.what would be the behaviour?
@Richard

Comment: I updated my answer. But in short, you can do everything except see source code and variable names, without the source file.